# WSL: Keeping ssh private key accessible as long as I don't restart Windows 10 (like the behaviour of pageant)

Tags: windows, openssh, gui, terminal-emulator, powershell

So far on Windows 10 I used mainly the PuTTy bundle (PuTTygen, Pageant and PuTTy, etc) to SSH into remote Linux machines.

I use Pageant as a **private key holder** to hold to private key (and possible passphrase) in memory as long as the PC isn't rebooted.

I'd like to use WSLs OpenSSH as client more often as with this command:

```
ssh USER@IP -vvv -L 22:localhost:22 # Or USER@DOMAIN.TLD;
```

Yet I didn't find a Pageant like behavior on WSL OpenSSH:

> Holding the SSH key in memory for all possible WSL shells (even in shell termination) until the
>   machine itself is rebooted from whatever reason

How could I have a Pageant-like behavior in WSL OpenSSH?

Comment: ssh-agent in linux. But beware WSL is not your linux kernel

Comment: For the 99% of users here, that don't know what pageant is: Pageant is a part of putty (ssh for microsoft's windows). It is the equivalent of ssh-agent, and ssh-add (but graphical). It also puts an icon in the tray.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, but WSL is their Linux (kernel) replacement (like an understudy in acting, it is used when the better one is not available).

Answer (score 1):

You need `ssh-agent`, and `ssh-add`.

`ssh-agent` may be already started (it is on Debian), when you login. To test it, run `ssh-add -l`. You should see no keys, if the agent is working. If it is not running then you should get an error-message, saying something like can not connect to agent.

To add the key. If is is a default name, then you just have to do `ssh-add`, else you do `ssh-add «path/to/your/key/key-name»`, then you are prompted for the pass-phrase.

Answer (score 1):

On U*nix [`ssh-agent`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-agent) would be run ideally very early at session login. That's usually what is done on a GUI (X11 etc.) login. Beside deamonizing, this command leaves conveniently as output *shell commands* which export variables needed to contact the newly spawned daemon, ready for shell evaluation:

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-TO9z33k5zo6t/agent.25671; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=25673; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 25673;
```

run again as intended from a posix sh shell:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 25965
$ printenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID
/tmp/ssh-XgTqsra2Pok2/agent.25964
25965
```

If this is run by a common ancestor process during login setup, all further processes will inherit these variables, making the running `ssh-agent` available for use anywhere in the session.

Also to be noted that (part of) those variables can be inherited via a remote `ssh` using the agent forwarding option (`-A`), without then requiring a local `ssh-agent`.

---

Now, for the case where the same user wants to reuse `ssh-agent`, but from an other unrelated access (other terminal, session, be it remote or local etc.) which didn't inherit the two previous exported variables because there's no mechanism in place. That user can just retrieve their value from wherever needed: an other terminal running a shell having them already exported, some file at a fixed position created by a script designed to save those variables (or better the commands above before evaluation) for this specific purpose, etc.) and export them again:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XgTqsra2Pok2/agent.25964; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=25965; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

So if on some terminal one ran instead of `eval $(ssh-agent)` something like this:

```
$ mkdir -m 700 -p ~/.ssh-agent-info
$ ssh-agent > ~/.ssh-agent-info/variables
$ . ~/.ssh-agent-info/variables
Agent pid 25965
```

then started adding some keys:

```
$ ssh-add /tmp/demokey
Enter passphrase for /tmp/demokey: 
Identity added: /tmp/demokey
$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:Ayd3PCiSkVVV09IqwEXz2Fn3nuXF70FDPMlNtZiuTtY user@host (ED25519)
```

and that user on others terminals on the same system sourced again the same variables, should get the expected result:

```
$ . ~/.ssh-agent-info/variables
Agent pid 25965
$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:Ayd3PCiSkVVV09IqwEXz2Fn3nuXF70FDPMlNtZiuTtY user@host (ED25519)
```

Meaning that there's no need to give anymore the passphrase until `ssh-agent` is killed or asked to forget its keys.

This should be working about the same on any platform with a port of *openssh* and `ssh-agent`, so I believe the same should work on WSL.

Ideally you should put those commands in a shell startup script (like `.profile`), crafted in such a way that it will first detect if (the correct) `ssh-agent` is already running before attempting to spawn a new one, else you will leak processes and will have to give again a passphrase.